# Using add method with local variables and Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I am working my way through a DSC script resource and part of it involves the use of `Invoke-Command` on a remote server. Part of what I am trying to do it populate a local list object. The reason this needs to be done on a remote host is the required module for Configuration Manger (SCCM) needs to be on a system that has the management console installed.

I am attempting to use the `.Add()` method with the local variable in a remote session, like this:

```
$UpdateGroupMembers = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Creds -ScriptBlock {
        foreach ($Collection in $Using:UpdateCollections) {
            $Member = Get-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule -CollectionId $Collection
            $Using:UpdateGroupMembers.Add($Member)
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error that the "Expression is not allowed in a `Using` expression." Is there anyway around this? Am I approaching it wrong?

Comment: Why not just have the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock output the group members to add, and capture that in `$UpdateGroupMembers`?

Comment: I dont have the means to test this at this time but have you tried passing `$UpdateGroupMembers` as an argument to the `invoke-command` scriptblock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$using:` is a scope modifier. Scope modifiers can only be used with variable names.

What you want is to call a local method on a local variable within your script block. To accomplish this, return the result and use it to populate the object.

```
$GroupMembers = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $Creds -ScriptBlock {
    $UpdateGroupMembers = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    foreach ($Collection in $Using:UpdateCollections) {
        $Member = Get-CMDeviceCollectionDirectMembershipRule -CollectionId $Collection
        [void]$UpdateGroupMembers.Add($Member)
    }
    $UpdateGroupMembers
}
```

The above defines the list on the remote computer, populates it there, and stores the list as a result of the execution in `$GroupMembers`.

Side note: the `[void]` cast is to prevent the `List.Add()` method from returning unwanted data.

Comment: This worked, thanks for the code and explanation. one follow up Q though: If I declare $UpdateGroupMembers at the top of the script (outside of the `Test Script` block where this code is) would `using:` then be appropriate?

Comment: `using:` would be appropriate in that case. However, `using:` only accepts a variable name, which means that if you try and call a method on it, it will fail. You might be able to do that if you put it in parenthesis: `($using:UpdateGroupMembers).Add($Member)`. I can't test that though. You should let me know if that works